# how to get image from AGImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using AGImagePickerController for selecting the multiple images at a time and get its information. It is working fine and getting the selected image array like this:

ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:{\n \"public.jpeg\" = \"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=C2CFE6EA-8B51-45BB-934A-486DDC1454B5&ext=JPG\";\n}", "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:{\n \"public.png\" = \"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=D8B1E72A-A53F-4DC6-B0EC-21508CB4FA00&ext=PNG\";\n}

But I don't know how to further use this to get the image and send it to facebook. If anyone know how to get the image from above url please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

```
  -(void)agImagePickerController:(AGImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{

     for(ALAsset *asset in info)
    {
       ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
        NSLog(@"%@",img);
    }
}
```

Here are 2 screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am using AGImagePickerController. I mentioned wrong one.

Comment: have you implemented the delegate method i wrote above?

Comment: Yes I wrote. But It didn't jump to that method.;(

Comment: Are you sure you set the viewController as delegate.

Comment: And if you got that asset above you can use this : ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
        NSLog(@"%@",img);

Comment: Can you run this https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController and please tell me where should I make changes?

Comment: that is the one i used to test, i just added that delegate method in  AGImagePickerController

Comment: Yes. I can send the project to you, I use 6.1 Simulator.

Comment: Can I ask one more question?

Comment: Okay , what is the question?

Comment: when user done on click button Should I save all the images url to the array. Actually I want to post the images to feedback on button click after done button.

Comment: You could only cache the images in an array because the user can upload the same image twice or as many times he needs, then you can use them as you want where you want as long as you have acces to the array.

Comment: How to save cache of images into an array?

Comment: I meant you save the UIImage in the array with [mutableArray addObject:img];

Comment: Where you have made changes in the given project

Comment: i didn't find any change..;(

Comment: Run the project , select the images and press done and let me know if the first image appears above the button.

Comment: With pleasure , let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: In this sample code we are able to get all pictures of particular album. But Can I get Album pictures without movie to its detail page?

Comment: Don't know that, maybe you could if you would alter the controller , so you get the images without presenting them. If this is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm sure somewhere deep within the class you could use the ALAsset array to your own use, but that needs additional work , I haven't tried it so far, but you should give it a try.

Comment: Yup I will surely try to do this